# Python local variable defined in an enclosing scope referenced before assignment in multiple functions

Tags: python, class, global-variables

I have the following code:

```
class MyFirstClass:
    
    def myDef(self):
        global x, y
        x = 'some_str'
        y = 0

class MySecondClass:

    def myOtherDef(self):
        for i in range(10):
            y += 1
            if y % 2 == 0:
                y = 0
                x = 'new_str'
```

However, `y += 1` errors with `local variable 'y' defined in an enclosing scope on line 4 referenced before assignment`

How can I re-assign variable `y` in the new class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues with this. The first is that you need to define `x` and `y` as members of `MyFirstClass`, not as `globals` in a method. You won't be able to access them that way. The second is that you need an instance of `MyFirstClass` in `MySecondClass`:

```
class MyFirstClass:
    x = 'some_str'
    y = 0
        
class MySecondClass:
    myFirstClass = MyFirstClass()
    def myOtherDef(self):
        for i in range(10):
            self.myFirstClass.y += 1
            if self.myFirstClass.y % 2 == 0:
                self.myFirstClass.y = 0
                self.myFirstClass.x = 'new_str'
                print(self.myFirstClass.x)


mySecondClass = MySecondClass()
mySecondClass.myOtherDef()
```

Output:

```
new_str
new_str
new_str
new_str
new_str
```